# How can i enable Group calender?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I found that the "EnablePeopleSelector" property changes the calender into a group calender.

I am unable to set the value for tat property using csom or webservices..
My webservices snippet is as follows

```
    Dim xDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    Dim ndProperties As XmlNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "List", "")
    Dim ndPeopleSelector As XmlAttribute = CType(xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute,"EnablePeopleSelector", ""), XmlAttribute)



    ndPeopleSelector.Value = "True"


    ndProperties.Attributes.Append(ndPeopleSelector)
    Dim xn As XmlNode = list.UpdateList(node.Attributes("Name").Value, ndProperties, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Where have i gone wrong?
Is there any possible workaround using either csom or Webservices.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in CSOM:

```
        var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList list = web.Lists["Calendar"];            
        list.EnablePeopleSelector = true;
        list.Update();
```